# Lambert W-Function with numerical

Tags: complex-analysis

$\ln x+x=1$
I am looking for solution of this equation. However, I am not able to find any simple way to solve this problem. Please help me to solve this problem by steps by steps as a result I will be able to understand.

Comment: What is with $x=1$?

Comment: $x=1$, satisfies $\ln x+x=1$

Comment: This is the only real solution!

Comment: @ArunChand: When all else fails, start with a plot: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(x)+%2B+x+%3D+1

Comment: Why do you mention Lambert W in the title (and only there) ? By the way, your title is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

This approach gives you the only real solution to the transcendental equation. To find other complex solutions consider the many other branches of the Lambert $W$ function. $$\begin{align*}\ln x+x=1\\ \ln x+\ln e^x=1\\ \ln xe^x=1\\ xe^x=e\\ \boxed{x=W_0(e)=1}\end{align*}$$

Comment: "This approach": which one ? The OP didn't give any.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I meant the one that follows. :)

Answer (score 1):

**A simple way to solve:**

A grapher seems to show a root of $\ln x+x-1$ at $\color{green}{x=1}$, which you confirm numerically.

As the derivative $\dfrac1x+1$ is positive, the function is monotonous and there cannot be other roots.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for methods of representing this solution in terms of elementary functions, (e.g. ln *x*, *e*<sup>*x*</sup>, *x*<sup>2</sup>) this is an on-going study in mathematics. (Here are some resources: [Lambert-W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), [Closed-form representations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265537796_Closed-form_representations_of_the_Lambert_W_function))
However, just as the solution to "tan *x* = *e*" can be written as:

> *x* = arctan(*e*) = *i*/2 log(1 - *i e*) - *i*/2 log(1 + *i e*) ≈ 1.218

We can write the equation "ln *x* + *x* = 1" in terms of the Lambert-W function as well. Of course, arctan(*x*) can be represented precisely, but keep in mind the idea of inverse functions.

Let's raise *e* to the power of both sides:

> *e* <sup>ln *x* + *x*</sup> = *e* <sup>1</sup>

Because both sides are equal by definition, *e* to the power of one side *must* be equal to *e* to the power of the other. Next, using the exponential property of

> a<sup>b + c</sup> = a<sup>b</sup> * a<sup>c</sup>

we get

> *e* <sup>ln *x*</sup> * *e* <sup>*x*</sup> = *e*

Next, we can use the identity *e* <sup>ln *x*</sup> = *x*, giving us

> *xe* <sup>*x*</sup> = *e*

The definition of the Lambert-W function is that *W*(*ze* <sup>*z*</sup>) = *z*, so by taking the *W* of both sides we get

> *W*(*xe* <sup>*x*</sup>) = *W*(*e*)
>
> *x* = *W*(*e*)

Now, there are two notable branches to the *W* function, namely *W*<sub>0</sub> and *W*<sub>1</sub>. *W*<sub>0</sub> deals with real numbers, which will end up giving us our assumed answer of 1, while *W*<sub>1</sub> solves for complex answers, giving a rather unintuitive answer. So:

> *W*<sub>0</sub> (*e*) = 1
>
> *W*<sub>1</sub> (*e*) ≈ -0.53209 + 4.59716 *i*

[Wolframalpha approximations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=productlog%5B0,%20e%5D,%20productlog%5B1,%20e%5D)

Comment: To a reader that has some understanding of complex functions, branches and the Lambert's $W$ function, does it make sense to be so detailed ?

Comment: Uh, because they not only asked for step-by-step instructions, but because the OP won't be the only reader. Answers should either describe or at least point in the direction of description

Comment: You should explain the theory of complex variables step by step as well.

Comment: Bub, you are not needed here. Answer some other question with your pedanticism